# How do add single datapoints after a chart review in R

Tags: r, variables, merge, review

I am trying to add my new data collected from a chart review into my database, but cant seem to get there.

I've tried programming a new variable and then using a logic function to pick which datapoint to use, but using a whole variable is not working, as it is a vector and not a single datapoint. How can I programm it to use the datapoint from the same observation but a different variable?

```
mydf <- structure(list(Year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L),
                       Var1 = c(15, 12, 2, 16, NA), 
                       Var2 = c(15, 13, 104, NA, NA), 
                       Agree = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)), 
                  .Names = c("Year",  "Var1", "Var2", "Agree"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

## mydf

#    Year Var1 Var2 Agree
#  1 2014   15   15  1
#  2 2014   13   12  0
#  3 2015    2  104  0
#  4 2015   16   NA  1
#  5 2016   NA   NA  1


mydf$true <- if_else(mydf$Agree == 1, mydf$Var1, mydf$Var2) 

## Error Message
# Error: `true` must be length 0 (length of `condition`) or one, not 5.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

## What I want
#   Year Var1 Var2 Agree True
# 1 2014   15   15     1   15
# 2 2014   13   12     0   12
# 3 2015    2  104     0  104
# 4 2015   16   NA     1   16
# 5 2016   NA   NA     1   NA
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I get the right output when I do your code. the error might be due to the fact that you loaded multiple packages with function `if_else`.

Comment: maybe try function ifelse instead of if_else ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which packages you have initially. I did it this way and got the answer you needed:

```r
mydf <- structure(list(Year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L),
                       Var1 = c(15, 12, 2, 16, NA), 
                       Var2 = c(15, 13, 104, NA, NA), 
                       Agree = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)), 
                  .Names = c("Year",  "Var1", "Var2", "Agree"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
    
library(dplyr)
    
mydf$true <- if_else(mydf$Agree == 1, mydf$Var1, mydf$Var2)
```

Comment: You could use more `dplyr` verbs here: `mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(true = if_else(Agree == 1, Var1, Var2))`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Maël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460602/ma%C3%ABl) pointed out, you probably loaded multiple packages with the if_else function. To fix this error you can specify the package you want to use.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf$true <- dplyr::if_else(mydf$Agree == 1, mydf$Var1, mydf$Var2)
```

A small addition, which will be helpful for you in the long run in working with R, I recommend you to deal with `dplyr` and `mutate`. Check the code below as an example for your issue above:

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(True = ifelse(Agree == 1, Var1, Var2))
```